# Web based tool to upload csvs -> sql table, query, and invite/ share tables with others?

Tags: web-apps, web-browser, sql

I'm looking for a website that can take multiple csvs/tsvs/jsons, generate SQL tables that I can run queries against, and that's shareable with others (invite people and have them run queries against the tables), and that's possibly free? I'm using this to interview people, and would prefer something that doesn't require them to download additional software/ can be accessed through the web itself.

I found these two websites, but they don't appear shareable/ are localized to your browsers instance.

https://dumbmatter.com/csv-sql-live/
https://www.convertcsv.com/query-csv.htm

Flatbase would be prefect, but it's signup and invite process seems to be broken. Invitation emails aren't being sent out, and signing up with a gmail/ outlook email breaks into a signup loop, so it isn't ideal.
https://flatbase.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this which works, thought I'd share it. It doesn't let you share Postgres DBs, only SQLite though, but it's perfect for running basic queries, and is free.

https://sqliteonline.com/

Comment: It's great that you fond something )+1). Don't forget to accept your own answer, which will help others who read the question in future (you may have to wait 2 days until the system will let you)